# A mod_rewrite rule to map all paths to index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a script at www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/index.php. I want to map all requests to subdirectories of mydirectories to the script. For instance, www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/mypath/ should be rewritten to www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/index.php/mypath/

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: We're assuming that this on the Apache web server. If it isn't then you will have to mention which it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the .htaccess file in your *mydirectory* directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $0 !^index\.php/
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: This cause the server to return an 404 error, which I interpret as that the server is looking for the physical subdirectory but not finding any (cause there are no physical subdirectories).

Can it be made such that it does not look for the physical subdirectory but instead effectively make a new HTTP request to the given subdirectory?

Thanks.

Comment: @Anders Feder - Make sure that you've [set `AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) correctly as well. `mod_rewrite` is essentially making a new internal request, it's just problematic sometimes (for whatever reason) to create `PATH_INFO` in the process.

Answer (score 0):

This will forward all requests to **index.php** if a requested file or folder doesn't exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

For example, `http://www.example.com/category/5/` becomes `http://www.example.com/index.php/category/5/`

You can parse the path behind **index.php** using explode() and $HTTP_SERVER_VARS

```
$url = explode('/', $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PATH_INFO']);
```

Comment: My RewriteRule I've used is > RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT] -- I also had this just below RewriteEngine On > RewriteBase / -- Either way, this should work.